# Calling Restful WCF POST method object as parameter from androeid

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I am working on Android application and I have problem when calling my "POST" request wcf RESTful service from android app.

This is my wcf service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "finalProductList", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string finalProductList(Productdetails[] objprod);

public string finalProductList(Productdetails[] objprod)
        {
            try
            {
                BasicConfigurator.Configure();
                log.Info("finalProductList method fired ");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("\"jsonResult\":[");
                int result = 0;
                string json = objprod.ToString();
                JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);
                JArray items = (JArray)rss["finalProductList"];
                for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
                {
                    string Merchantid = string.Empty;
                    string MerchantName = string.Empty;
                    alperm.Clear();
                    alperm.Add(new SqlParameter("@Merchantid", (string)rss["finalProductList"][i]["merchant_id"]));
                    alperm.Add(new SqlParameter("@MerchantName", (string)rss["finalProductList"][i]["merchant_name"]));
                    result = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlConnection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Sp_InsProductDetails", (SqlParameter[])alperm.ToArray(typeof(SqlParameter)));
                }
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    sb.Append("{\"success\": true" + ",\"message\":Data Inserted Successfully!}]");
                    return sb.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append("{\"success\": false" + ",\"message\":No input data retrived!}]");
                    return sb.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("finalProductList : Error while inserting producet details: " + ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Android code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", jsonStr));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
System.out.println("Response : " + response)
```

I enable logos in wcf method. When i am calling wcf method from android app this method not getting fired and getting an error in android:

```
 W/System.err(1603): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
```

Comment: You're sending the request in a URL-encoded format (e.g., data=jsonStr), which is not valid JSON. Try sending only the JSON to the server, and set the appropriate content-type (i.e., application/json).

Comment: i change that but no use getting same error.

Comment: Try enabling tracing at the server side, it should show you why WCF is considering the request to be bad.

Comment: I am getting this error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path '', line 0, position 0.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)
  at RestService.RestServiceImpl.finalProductList(Productdetails[] jobjprod)

Comment: Then your method is being called, the error is in its implementation. Try logging the values you have, or debugging into it, and you should have more details about what is going wrong.